# emit url query string using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

When a user fills the form data which has one input in the name of 'uname' , after submitting the form, the form data is send to the server using socket.io and the user is directed to '/website.html' and the form data is appended to the url like http://localhost:3000/website.html?uname=rohan.

In '/website.html', there are some buttons which all directs to some other html files and when we click on the buttons a new socket connection is made.

I just want  that when we click on the buttons in '/website.html', server sends the 'uname' value appended in http://localhost:3000/website.html?uname=rohan to the client. 
P.S. i know a different socket is connection is made on clicking the buttons in '/website.html' different to the socket connection  which was made after submitting the form to send the form data to server.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want to achieve and why, your question is unclear.

Comment: I have edited it and tried to make it clearer. .Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then you need to first setup your router connections. If that's setup up correctly, for example when you click the button, it at least pulls the correct page with the query string.

What you could do then, is setup your front end side to read in the parameters from the query string to do what you need it to do accordingly.

You haven't really said what your particular stack is, so that as much information I can give you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But i solved the problem using passport.socketio. .In it,.req.session.user will give me the user-details.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes here, there is a client side solution.

To keep query parameters on connect and in subsequent emits as well, you connect the socket like this:

`var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890?query=foobar', {path: "mypath"});`

with the optional path shown, and future socket emits it will automatically move the query string to the correct place and query the url like this:

`http://localhost:8890/mypath/?query=foobar&EIO=3&transport=polling...`